# How do I approach $ a\frac{\partial I}{\partial a} + b\frac{\partial I}{\partial b} + c\frac{\partial I}{\partial c} = \frac{\pi}{2}?$

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, education, linear-pde

How do I solve this partial differential equation:
$$ a\frac{\partial I}{\partial a} + b\frac{\partial I}{\partial b} + c\frac{\partial I}{\partial c} = \frac{\pi}{2} ?$$

Is there a way to approach this partial differential equation via Lagrange's partial differential equation for 3 variables?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Observe that your left hand side is the directional derivative of $I$ at the point $(a , b,c)$ in the direction $(a, b,c)$ so it is a radial derivative. Your radial derivative is constant, so you should be able to write down all possible solutions.

Comment: This is the transport equation

Answer (score 0):

$$ a\frac{\partial I}{\partial a} + b\frac{\partial I}{\partial b} + c\frac{\partial I}{\partial c} = \frac{\pi}{2} $$
$$\frac{da}{a}=\frac{db}{b}=\frac{dc}{c}=\frac{dI}{\pi/2}$$
Change of variables :
$$a=e^x\quad;\quad b=e^y\quad;\quad c=e^z \quad;\quad I=\frac{\pi}{2}x+J(x,y,z)$$
$$ \frac{\partial J}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial J}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial J}{\partial z} = 0 $$
I suppose that you can find (or something equivalent) :
$$J(x,y,z)=F\big((x-y),(y-x),(z-x) \big)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function until no condition is specified.

This result can be expressed on many equivalent forms of functions of $\frac{a}{b},\frac{b}{c},\frac{c}{a}$.